# jQuery - Tab Slide Out

Tags: jquery, tabs, slide

I am using a plugin from here:
http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

This works great except when I try add tabs on the left and right.

Does anyone know of a plugin that supports tabs on both sides of the screen at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the current plugin. If anyone else has this problem when creating multiple tabs simply copy the current settings function, change your ID and orientation ie ('left or right') and make sure your triggers are not the same class name. I added a unique class to each one, ie ('first, second, third') and now it works fine with tabs on the left and right.